# How do I comment the first line of a pattern block where all lines should be commented?

Tags: sed, block, matching

I have a pattern block like this:

```
<domain hotmail.com>
blah
blah
blah
</domain>
```

I want the final output to look like this:

```
#<domain hotmail.com>
#blah
#blah
#blah
#</domain>
```

Using this command I can get all but the 1st line which is the match to start the pattern:

```
sed -e "/\(^<domain hotmail.com>\)/{:a;n;s/^/#/;/<\/domain>/!ba;}" file
```

Which give me this:

```
<domain hotmail.com>
#blah
#blah
#blah
#</domain>
```

The number of lines between  and  will vary.  The above code works for the variance but not on the first line.  How can I get the first line commented?

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 2):

```
sed '/<domain hotmail\.com>/,/<\/domain>/ s/^/#/'
```

Testing:

```
sed '/<domain hotmail\.com>/,/<\/domain>/ s/^/#/' <<END
foo
<domail yahoo.com>
blah
blah
</domain>
qux
<domain hotmail.com>
blah
blah
blah
</domain>
bar
<domain gmail.com>
blah
</domain>
baz
END
```

```
foo
<domail yahoo.com>
blah
blah
</domain>
qux
#<domain hotmail.com>
#blah
#blah
#blah
#</domain>
bar
<domain gmail.com>
blah
</domain>
baz
```

Comment: Thanks Glenn!  I kind of over thought that didn't I?  I've never used the comma before and looked it up.  Nice.  Thanks for teaching me something.  I would up vote but I don't think I have enough points yet.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^<domain hotmail.com>$/{:a;N;/^<\/domain>$/M!ba;s/^/#/Mg} file
```

This will comment the tags and the values between if and only if both tags exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/^/#/'
```

**Example:**

```
sdlcb@ubuntu:~/AMD_C$ cat file 
<domain hotmail.com>
blah
blah
blah
</domain>
sdlcb@ubuntu:~/AMD_C$ sed 's/^/#/' file
#<domain hotmail.com>
#blah
#blah
#blah
#</domain>
```